# How do I access the XML element data in AS3 when its has no tag

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, xml-parsing, e4x

Here is the scenario:

OLD XML data was in the form of :

```
<data>
<![CDATA[[<span class='css'>SomeData XYZ</span>]]>
</data>
```

Now a sub element has cropped up in some of the data:

```
<data>
<![CDATA[[<span class='css'>SomeData XYZ</span>]]>
<subelement>
     SubData ABC
</subelement>
</data>
```

with the previous format you could get the "SomeData XYZ]]" using:  myXML.data

However, now if one tries that you get the entire body within the data tag including the subelements.

I also tried just myXML.data.text  but it returned nothing also tried   .*  (returned everything between data tags)

Stumped.

Comment: I think you're missing a `>` on each of those `CDATA` tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can access that link as the first child of `myXML`:

`var someData:String = myXML.children()[0];`

Edit: You said you tried `myXML.data.text`, if `data` is the root element, that won't work. You should try `myXML.text();` That *should* return any text within the `XML` that's not part of a child-element.

Comment: I did see this through the debugger, however that CDATA line may not always be the first line.